# Need to run .exe file for 7 seconds and then kill the exe while performing input and output in text files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to create a batch file which runs a program for 7 seconds, irrespective of the completion of execution of the other program. I also want that the program should take input and save the output in an external file. This is what I tried:

```
start program.exe
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 7000 > nul
taskkill /im program.exe /f
rem continue here
```

The above works fine, but when I replace line 1 with:

```
start program.exe < in.txt > out.txt
```

then input from file and output in file doesn't work.

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/338277/windows-cmd-batch-start-and-output-redirection) looks very similar - the problem currently is that you're redircting stdin/stdout for `start`, not for the program that `start` is executing

Comment: Try: `start "" "program.exe < in.txt > out.txt"`

Comment: @eryksun You should post those two comments as an answer.  Tag me when you do and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cmd doesn't set the `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag of the `CreateProcess` `STARTUPINFO` structure. Instead, it temporarily redirects its own standard handles and relies on inheritance. This approach works even if cmd has to call `ShellExecuteEx`, which lacks a way to explicitly set the standard handles.

However, redirecting its own standard handles doesn't work when `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` is set in the process creation flags, which is the default for the `start` command. To avoid this problem, use the `/b` option to prevent creating a new console.

You may also want to redirect stderr to stdout or a file. This prevents errors from being written to the console. For example:

- `start /b program.exe <in.txt >out.txt 2>&1`
- `start /b program.exe <in.txt >out.txt 2>err.txt`
- `start /b program.exe <in.txt >out.txt 2>nul`

---

Example using [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551063)

```
(test) C:\>cdb -Goxi ld cmd

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: cmd
Symbol search path is: symsrv*symsrv.dll*
C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is:
(ed0.1770): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00000000`77848700 cc              int     3
0:000> .reload /f
Reloading current modules
.....
0:000> bp CreateProcessW
0:000> g
```

Run where.exe in a new console.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

(test) C:\>start /w where.exe <nul >nul
Breakpoint 0 hit
kernel32!CreateProcessW:
00000000`775a0660 4883ec68        sub     rsp,68h
```

Note that cmd.exe redirects its `StandardOutput` before calling `CreateProcess`:

```
0:000> ?? ((ntdll!_PEB *)@$peb)->ProcessParameters->StandardOutput
void * 0x00000000`00000060

0:000> !handle 60 3
Handle 60
  Type          File
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x120196:
         ReadControl,Synch
         Write/Add,Append/SubDir/CreatePipe,WriteEA,ReadAttr,WriteAttr
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  3
```

The process creation flags, i.e. `dwCreationFlags`, the 6th parameter:

```
0:000> dd (@rsp + 6*8) l1
00000000`00182c58  00080410
```

is passed as 0x80410, which is a bitwise OR of the following flags:

- `EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT`
- `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT`
- `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`

Because a new console is created, where.exe doesn't inherit cmd's standard handles:

```
0:000> g
Symbol search path is: symsrv*symsrv.dll*
C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is:
(1550.1a80): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00000000`77848700 cc              int     3

1:001> ?? ((ntdll!_PEB *)@$peb)->ProcessParameters->StandardOutput
void * 0x00000000`00000007
```

*Note: in Windows 8+ a console handle is just a regular file handle, so you'll have to look deeper.*

I'm using Windows 7 for this example, so console handles are fake handles tagged by setting the lower 2 bits (e.g. 3, 7, 11 => 0b0011, 0b0111, 0b1011). By 'fake' I mean they're not in the process handle table used for kernel object handles. Thus, for example, you can't use the debugger `!handle` command to inspect handle 7:

```
1:001> !handle 7 f
Could not duplicate handle 7, error 87
```

In Windows 7, console handles are allocated and managed by the console host process, conhost.exe. They're tagged so Windows base functions can make the required LPC call to conhost.exe via `NtRequestWaitReplyPort`.

---

The above example demonstrated how creating a new console overrides inheriting cmd's redirected standard handles. Now let's add the `/b` option to prevent creating a new console.

```
1:001> g

(test) C:\>start /b /w where.exe <nul >nul
Breakpoint 0 hit
kernel32!CreateProcessW:
00000000`775a0660 4883ec68        sub     rsp,68h
```

`dwCreationFlags` is 0x80600:

```
0:000> dd (@rsp + 6*8) l1
00000000`00182c58  00080600
```

which is a bitwise OR of the following creation flags:

- `EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT`
- `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT`
- `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`

(A side effect of specifying `/b` is to create the process as the leader of a new process group. If it's a console process, this allows generating a Ctrl+Break event that targets the group.)

In this case, where.exe does inherit the redirected standard handles from cmd.exe:

```
0:000> g
Symbol search path is: symsrv*symsrv.dll*
C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is:
(1508.1534): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00000000`77848700 cc              int     3

1:001> ?? ((ntdll!_PEB *)@$peb)->ProcessParameters->StandardOutput
void * 0x00000000`00000064
1:001> !handle 64 3
Handle 64
  Type          File
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x120196:
         ReadControl,Synch
         Write/Add,Append/SubDir/CreatePipe,WriteEA,ReadAttr,WriteAttr
  HandleCount   3
  PointerCount  4
```

Again, in Windows 7 it's easy to spot a console pseudo handle because it's tagged by setting the low 2 bits of the handle value. For Windows 8+, a quick check is to look at the low nibble (4 bits) of the file's granted access, for which read data access is 1, write data access is 2, and append data access is 4.  A file opened for a console buffer has both read and write access, whereas cmd's redirection uses either read (`<`) or write (`>`), but not both. The above is the redirected output, and you can see the file is opened with write and append access (2+4), but not read access. That's a quick check, but if you want to be certain you can use a kernel debugger such as kd.exe, or a tool such as Sysinternals Process Explorer or handle.exe. These can show you the NT kernel object path, such as `\Device\ConDrv\Input` for a Windows 8+ console input handle.

Comment: Hi. I am very interested in know the details on how cmd.exe manage the redirection of several standard handles placed in a "chain", like the one described at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6610); this knowledge would allow us to use such feature based on real data instead of the trial and error method we use now. I looked at the Debugging Tools for Windows described at your link, but those tools are _huge!_ I wonder if you may be interested in help me to grasp the operation mechanism of this particular feature of cmd.exe. Thanks for your attention! **`:-)`**

Comment: @Aacini, file numbers such as 0 (stdin), 1 (stdout), and 2 (stderr) aren't Windows handles. They're the C runtime's low I/O file descriptors. Each is associated with a Windows handle. See the docs for [`_dup` and `_dup2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8syseb29) and [`_open_osfhandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x). A redirection such as `1>&2` will basically call `_dup(1)` (saved to restore after the command returns), `_close(1)`, `_dup2(2, 1)`.

Comment: @Aacini, Note that `_dup` and `_dup2` call Windows [`DuplicateHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724251) to duplicate the underlying Windows file handle. And `_open_osfhandle` calls [`SetStdHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686244) when it's assigning file descriptors 0, 1, or 2, which respectively correspond to `STD_INPUT_HANDLE`, `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE`, and `STD_ERROR_HANDLE`.

Comment: Yes. I know that this redirection `1>&2` is achieved by first `_dup(1)` and save the returned number, but suppose that the CRT file descriptor returned by `_dup(1)` is _the next available number_ like happened in DuplicateHandle function of old MS-DOS INT 21H, that is **3**. If the complete redirection would be `1>&2 3>&1`, is the file number 3 also duplicated via `_dup(3)` or not? Refers this file number 3 to _the same file descriptor_ previously returned by `_dup(1)` or not? As you can see, if we introduce more redirections and/or change their order, the final result can be very complicated!

Comment: @Aacini, debug a command that redirects `1>null 3>out.txt`, with breakpoints set on `msvcrt!dup`, `msvcrt!dup2`, `msvcrt!close`, and `msvcrt!open_osfhandle`. The sequence is `dup(1)` -> 3, `close(1)`, `open_osfhandle(hNull)` -> 1, `dup(3)` -> 4, `close(3)`, `open_osfhandle(hOut)` -> 3. The command runs, and then the saved file descriptors are restored: `dup2(3, 1)`, `close(3)`, `dup2(4, 3)`, `close(4)`. Here's a question for you. What's *hilariously* wrong with the restore sequence?

Comment: @Aacini, BTW, why do you say the debugging tools are huge? The web installer for the SDK lets you download and install just the debugging tools. You don't have to install the entire SDK.

Comment: That is not "hilariously wrong", but precisely the cause of our problems! See [this example](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6610&p=42631#p42631): "This will permanently disable stdout upon completion of the command: `3>&1 1>&2 4<test.txt`. At this point, the only thing you can do is kill your CMD session and start a new one". If you post the sequence of previous redirection and these ones: `4<test.txt 3>&1 1>&2` and `1>&2 9<test.txt`, I think we could deduce the redirection rules! **`;)`**

Comment: @Aacini, Setup: `dup2(1, 3)`, `dup(1)` -> 4, `close(1)`, `dup2(2, 1)`, `dup(4)` -> 5, `close(4)`
`open_osfhandle(hTest)` -> 4. Restore: `close(3)`, `dup2(4, 1)`, `close(4)`, `dup2(5, 4)`, `close(5)`. cmd incorrectly restores in creation order instead of in reverse. When it dupes 4 to 1 in the restore sequence, that's setting stdout to a file that was only opened for reading. If you inspect the `StandardOutput` handle, you'll see it's opened with access 0x120089, which tells us it's only opened for reading.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The discovery of this bug allow us to avoid it. Just a final question: in `1>&2 9<test.txt` after the `close(1)` and `dup2(2, 1)` of the first redirection, is there a `close(9)` or not? How is the `9<test.txt` part implemented?

Comment: @Aacini, `9<test.txt` is implemented as `open_osfhandle(hTest)` -> 4, `dup2(4, 9)`, `close(4)`. After the command runs it calls `close(9)`.

Comment: **Thank you** eryksun! **`:-)`**